# Kentico Form Values - Day, Time, URL Referrer

Tags: macros, kentico

I have hidden form fields that need to populate when the form is submitted with a Date, Time, Referral URLs ... I've been adding macros to the default value field with some success, but not 100%.

`{% currentdate %}` returns somewhat correct info (the date) but adds time like: 5/31/2016 12:00:00 AM

`{% currenttime %}` returns 00:00:00

`{% URLReferrer %}` returns empty

Am I using the right macro syntax, right macro, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy") %}    

{% DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") %}

{% CurrentDocument.URLReferrer %}
```

Comment: Still returns the same as above https://www.dropbox.com/s/ru1bn2lsyf9macy/Screenshot%202016-05-31%2011.05.50.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I've tested following macros on K9:

```
{% GetDateTime(CurrentDateTime, "MM dd yyyy")%}

{% CurrentBrowser.UrlReferrer #%}
```

For GetDateTime method you can use standard [date time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Getting closer .. referring URL is now tracking something... but the time is still off

Comment: i just tested from my personal page... the ReferringURL code still isnt' quite right. maybe we need a cookie set up or something? it is still recording the URL of the page that we submitted the form on, rather than the URL of the page that sent the visitor to the site in the first place

Comment: Hey Sal, I've tested the referring url on my end and it does work properly. Don't forget that the referrer url is coming from the browser which means that you really do need to come to your form page from somewhere else. If you refresh the page then the referrer will be the same page. Basically what you need to do is: Go to page A -> Go to page B (with form) and submit.

Answer (score 0):

Sal and I are  working on this together.. him more-so than I.

But even when starting at an external site: http://hw2zoo.com/test-links-for-suddath/  the results are the same. The Referring URL show us the URL of the page that the form resides on.

It should return the http://hw2zoo.com/test-links-for-suddath/ link that led us to the site in the first place. Correct?

FYI.. time is working now ;) thanks for all of your help.